# Get the MySQL record that has less child-records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 2 MySQL tables like that:

```
Table: WIFI_Spots
*********************
ID  |  Name
1   |  Foo
2   |  Bar

Table: WIFI_Users
*********************
Spot_ID  |  User_ID  |  Status
1        |  3h8n26j  |  active
1        |  h6m78v2  |  inactive
2        |  3v9bn4y  |  active
2        |  6f9ftfx  |  active
```

In that case i want to get the WIFI spot that has the less active users in it based on `status`.

So even if there was many inactive users, those wouldn't be counted.

P.S. In the example, the result would be the Spot 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT    COUNT(s.ID)
FROM      WIFI_Spots s
LEFT JOIN WIFI_Users u ON u.Spot_ID = s.ID
WHERE     u.Status = 'active'
GROUP     BY s.ID
ORDER     BY COUNT(u.Spot_ID)
LIMIT     1
```